# How to make a reverse Path

Tags: wpf, xaml, path

I have this code:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Margin="15">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="150,100">
                <ArcSegment Size="50,50" Point="50,50" />
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

And the resulting Path is this:

[image]

I want to make the reverse Path:

[image]

But I want to make this without turn the StartPoint and the ArcSegment Point, because I need this Path to make a DoubleAnimationUsingPath (If I set StartPoint to 50,50 and the ArcSegmentPoint to 150,100, the figure is ok, but the animation goes in reverse mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this particular case is quite easy, simply set `SweepDirection="Clockwise"` on your ArcSegment. If this was just an example and not your actual use-case you might want to include more code (e.g. the Animation).

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Margin="15">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="150,100">
                <ArcSegment SweepDirection="Clockwise" Size="50,50" Point="50,50" />
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Just in case you need it, there is also a `IsLargeArc` setting that you could toggle once you reach a certain threshold (depends on your use-case).

Example Result:

[image: Example Animation Result]